# Run Completion Block Multiple Times, 'One By One'

Tags: objective-c

I have a piece of code (with a completion block) which I'd like to run multiple times (from a FOR loop) but I only want the operation to occur one by one.

To try and explain this a little better... (Max Concurrent Operation = 1, Items in For() Loop = 3)

1. Begin For() at item 0
2. Start *operation* for item 0
3. Completion of *operation* for item 0
4. Loop For() at item 1
5. Start *operation* for item 1
6. Completion of *operation* for item 1
7. Loop For() at item 2
8. Start *operation* for item 2
9. Completion of *operation* for item 2
10. End For() at item 2

Have made this solution, but it seems to run all at once and not one by one..

```
    // Batch download
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

    for (Item *item in ItemArray) {
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            if (![[ItemClient sharedClient] isCachedItem:item]) {
                // Item not yet cached

                [[ItemClient sharedClient] cacheItem:item completion:^(NSError *error) {
                        // Complete, next in FOR loop
                }];
            } else {
                // Item already cached
                // Complete, next in FOR loop
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding it to an NSOperationQueue? If you want it executed sequentially (synchronously) all you need to do is execute the block as a function: `block();`

Comment: You know one nutty solution is recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `[ItemClient cacheItem:completion:]` does some long-running piece of work before it calls the completion handler, and that's what you want to wait for before you start the next request.

Your code is not waiting for that completion handler, which is why the requests are all apparently happening in parallel.  You need to wait for the completion to be called before allowing the next operation in the queue to begin.

The easiest thing to do might be to rewrite `[ItemClient cacheItem:completion:]` so that it is synchronous.  In other words, it simply does the work, blocking the current thread, and doesn't need the completion parameter.  The NSOperationQueue is putting these operations onto a background thread for you anyway, so you can just use that thread to do your work.

Alternatively, you could use a semaphore to block until the completion callback happens:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[[ItemClient sharedClient] cacheItem:item completion:^(NSError *error) {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```